# Get failed query in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, typo3

I've a preparedstatement insert query. I want to implement an email notification system if that insert query fails. How can I identify the failed queries?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO user_persons ( NAME, DATE, ADDRESS, PINCODE ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $name, $date, $address, $pincode );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: mysqli and pdo return boolean false on failure, by default. so `$result = $stmt->execute(); if ($result === false ) { die("query failed"); }`

Comment: if(!$stmt->execute()){ // write your mail() function here.}

Comment: Actually your statement should not fail ever. If it's depending on some of the params, validate them before statement execution and do not try to execute statement it if they're invalid.

Comment: @biesior; yes I've handled almost all the scenarios there. But I want to ensure the functionality using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this.

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){ 
   // write your mail() function here.
}
```